# I am struggling with a join query. I want to display first_check_in and last_check_out for given date?

Tags: mysql

I wanted to obtain the first_check_in and last_check_out of an employee for the current day. Below is my MySQL database structure.

```
id | employee_id  | check_in             | check_out           
--------------------------------------------------------------
 1 | 2103         | 2019-09-15 07:30:00  | 2019-09-15 09:20:00  
 2 | 2103         | 2019-09-15 10:35:00  | null
 3 | 2103         | 2019-09-16 08:00:00  | 2019-09-16 10:00:00
 4 | 2103         | 2019-09-16 08:00:00  | 2019-09-16 18:00:00
 5 | 2095         | 2019-09-16 08:30:00  | 2019-09-16 18:30:00
```

And my query should return me

```
id | employee_id  | check_in             | check_out           
--------------------------------------------------------------
 1 | 2103         | 2019-09-15 07:30:00  | null
 3 | 2103         | 2019-09-16 08:00:00  | 2019-09-16 18:00:00
 5 | 2095         | 2019-09-16 08:30:00  | 2019-09-16 18:30:00
```

I have tried to write the following code:

```
  SELECT `employees`.`*`, 
    CONCAT(IFNULL(employees.first_name,''),' ',IFNULL(employees.surname,'')) as full_name, 
    `teams`.`description`, 
    `time_groups`.`start`, 
    `time_groups`.`end`,
    cast(a1.check_in as date) AS date,
    cast(a1.check_in as TIME) AS first_check_in,
    cast(a2.check_out as TIME) AS last_check_out
    FROM `employees` 
    JOIN `teams` 
    ON `employees`.`team_id` = `teams`.`id`  
    JOIN `time_groups` 
    ON `teams`.`time_group_id` = `time_groups`.`id`  
    JOIN `attendance_employees` AS a1
    JOIN `attendance_employees` AS a2
    ON `employees`.`id` = `a2`.`employee_id` 
    AND `a1`.`employee_id` = `a2`.`employee_id` 
    AND DATE(a1.check_in) = DATE(a2.check_out)
    WHERE  1 = 1
    GROUP BY a1.employee_id, a1.check_in, a2.check_out
```

but I am getting the following results:

```
Full Name   Date       Normal Work Hours    First Check In  Last Check Out
John        2019-09-15  08:00-16:30           07:30            09:20    
John        2019-09-15  08:00-16:30           10:35            09:20
```

expected "Last Check Out" to leave blank

```
   Full Name    Date       Normal Work Hours  First Check In    Last Check Out
   John         2019-09-15  08:00-16:30           07:30
```

Thanks in advances for your help and sorry for my English.

Updated:
Here is db structure for time_groups:

```
id | name              | start     | end
------------------------------------------
1  | Day Shift         | 08:00:00  | 16:30:00
2  | Day 07:00-15:30   | 07:00:00  | 15:30:00
6  | Night:12:00-19:00 | 12:00:00  | 19:00:00
```

and for teams:

```
id | description
------------------
1  | Accounts   
2  | Developers
```

Comment: can you also provide the other tables you want to join?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this solution for Oracle.
In order to 'convert' it to MySQL, you should only change the `TRUNC` function into `CAST(check_in_out AS DATE)`.

```
SELECT          tab1.employee_id,
                TRUNC(tab1.check_in) AS working_day,
                MIN(tab1.check_in) AS first_check_in,
                CASE WHEN tab2.employee_id IS NULL THEN MAX(tab1.check_out)
                     ELSE NULL
                END AS last_check_out
FROM            attendance_employees tab1
LEFT OUTER JOIN attendance_employees tab2
             ON tab1.employee_id = tab2.employee_id
            AND TRUNC(tab1.check_in) = TRUNC(tab2.check_in)
            AND tab2.check_out IS NULL
GROUP BY        tab1.employee_id,
                TRUNC(tab1.check_in),
                tab2.employee_id
ORDER BY        tab1.employee_id,
                working_day;
```

This assumes that for every employee/date there is at most 1 record with check_out being NULL.

Answer (score 0):

AS per your requirement and db structure i have created one sql query, Hope this will help you.

```
SELECT employee_id, CAST(check_in AS DATE) AS DATE,
MIN(TIME(check_in)) AS CHECK_IN, MAX(TIME(check_out)) AS CHECK_OUT 
FROM attendance_employees
GROUP BY employee_id, CAST(check_in AS DATE), CAST(check_out AS DATE)
ORDER BY CAST(check_in AS DATE)
```

DB FIDDLE LINK: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=586d7c606e2aed431a15eba9282e61fb

Comment: By grouping on `CAST(check_out AS DATE)` you get 2 records for 15/09. Removing that, you still get `09:20` as last check out.